# Sobre la posición de un pronombre en un verbo compuesto: "hacerlo dormir" o "hacer dormirlo"

Tags: verbos, pronombres

¿Cual es la diferencia entre *hacerlo dormir* y *hacer dormirlo*? O similares, no encuentro una diferencia aparente.

Comment: En qué caso usarías la segunda opción? La verdad así como está no suena correcto. Tienes algún contexto?

Comment: Yo no usaría la segunda opción. Me suena terrible.

Comment: Yo creo que es incorrecto decirlo así, sólo me gustaría saber en qué caso lo ha escuchado Weijie.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido/a a [spanish.se]! Intenta [edit]ar tu pregunta con ejemplos y todo aquello que pueda resultar de utilidad para hacerla más entendible. Puedes leer también [ask].

Comment: Si quieres poner el _lo_ con _dormir_, tienes que decir _hacer **que lo duerman**_, pero el significado cambia, porque entonces es una acción que se delega en otros.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Solo la opción *hacerlo dormir* es correcta.

---

La restricción de la colocación del pronombre clítico con verbos de influencia aparentemente no se trata en la sección [*pronombres personales átonos*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF) del [DPD](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/dpd). En la [Nueva gramática](http://www.rae.es/recursos/gramatica/nueva-gramatica) se trata el tema para el verbo *hacer* a partir de la sección [16.13j](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OMFYrgQgzTNRVLzj) y hasta la 16.13l. En la sección 16.13k encontramos (énfasis añadido):

> **16.13k** Se ha observado en los estudios sobre los pronombres átonos que se aplica a varios verbos, casi siempre de percepción, causación o juicio, una restricción de animacidad que no parece ser efectiva con los verbos de otros grupos. **Esos verbos admiten la anteposición de pronombres átonos de acusativo cuando se refieren a cosas, pero la rechazan cuando designan personas.** Los pares siguientes muestran estas alternancias. El primer infinitivo de cada uno de ellos tiene como complemento un pronombre que designa **una cosa** (*comprarla, leerlo, escribirlo*), mientras que el segundo infinitivo tiene un complemento de **persona** (*saludarla, visitarlo, contratarlo*):
>
> - No me permitieron (comprarla – saludarla); Le hizo (leerlo – respetarlo); Le obligaron a (escribirlo – contratarlo).
>
> Los pronombres átonos de los primeros infinitivos pueden anteponerse, pero los de los segundos rechazan la anteposición:
>
> - No me la permitieron (comprar – *saludar); Se lo hizo (leer – *respetar); Se lo obligaron a (escribir – *contratar).
>
> Tal como se deduce de estos contrastes, si *lo* en *contratarlo* designara un seguro (es decir, una entidad no personal), la anteposición resultaría natural.

En la frase ***Lo hacemos dormir** por lo menos 8 horas al día*<sup>1</sup>, en contraste con ***Hacemos dormirlo** por lo menos 8 horas al día*, no hace falta contexto para saber que *Lo hacemos dormir* es la única opción correcta, pues solo las cosas animadas pueden dormir. Con el verbo principal en infinitivo, a la hora de decidir a cuál de ellos debe añadirse el pronombre clítico, cabe citar el siguiente fragmento de la sección 16.13l:

> No son complementos directos del verbo subordinado, sino del principal, los pronombres átonos que aparecen en oraciones como *Lo vi arder* y otras que contienen infinitivos intransitivos (*Las hizo desaparecer*; *Los vi salir*).

Es decir, *lo* en *lo vi arder* complementa a *ver*, no a *arder*, por lo que suena más natural añadirlo a este y decir *Voy a verlo arder* en vez de *Voy a ver arderlo*. Lo mismo se puede decir de los demás ejemplos de la Nueva gramática y del compuesto *hacer dormir*. Si a ello se le suma que el sujeto de *dormir* solo puede ser un ente animado, se obtiene que solo *hacerlo dormir* es correcto.

---

<sup>1: Esta frase solo suena natural en dialectos no leístas. Entre los dialectos leístas se prefiere la oración ***Le** hacemos dormir por lo menos 8 horas al día*.</sup>

Comment: Qué son los países leístas? Yo tengo entendido que el *le* se usa sólo en España. ¿Algún otro lugar donde se use?

Comment: @VladimirNu No que yo sepa. Efectivamente, debería ser "dialecto" en ambos casos. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Paraguay es otro país leísta. También decimos "le hacemos dormir".

Comment: Tampoco toda España es leísta. Es más de algunas zonas del centro. En el sur o el este es bastante raro. Aunque ahora, debido a la influencia de la televisión, es algo más habitual que en los anos 70, por ejemplo.