# Use of direct objects with infinitives and simple future: "Voy a tirarlo" vs "Lo voy a tirar"

Tags: tiempos-verbales, objetos-directos

I am wondering about the use of the object 'lo' with infinitives, and also the simple future (using ir).

Which is preferred in these examples, and why?

- "Voy a lanzarlo" vs "Lo voy a lanzar"
- "Voy a comerlo" vs "Lo voy a comer"
- etc.

I feel like I prefer the lanzarlo/comerlo version but am I correct? Are both acceptable? Is there ever an acceptable situation for "Lo voy a ....."?

Comment: Related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17525/sobre-la-posici%c3%b3n-de-un-pronombre-en-un-verbo-compuesto-hacerlo-dormir-o-hac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are acceptable, correct, and both are used in [free variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variation) by native speakers, i.e. the same speaker will use either in any context without any reason, randomly.

Comment: You may want to add that historically, only "Voy a tirarlo" would have been considered correct at the beginning of an utterance, but nowadays it is more common (as evidenced by Google books) to prefer proclisis.

Comment: I'd only add that the pronoun in front position makes the DO slightly stronger than in end position: A: Quiero que lo tires ya - B: Ya dije que LO voy a tirar (slight emphasis on what is being thrown away rather than on the action of throwing - anything - away).

Comment: @Gustavson, that might be true in some cases, but I think that it does not usually make any difference. Do you have any references to that?

Comment: @Gustavson: I'm a native speaker, and I don't feel the difference that you point at. If I wanted to emphasize that I'm going to through "this" away, a opposed to something else, I would use something like "A esto (lo) voy a tirar(lo)"  (with exactly one of those two "lo", but never both). Without resorting to this kind of additions, the emphasis is going to be given by pronunciation alone.

Comment: @Wences I'm a native speaker, too. Notice that the double DO sentence should be "Esto (lo) voy a tirar(lo)", without "a" (reserved for personal and "personified" objects). I said the difference was slight, and as I see it it does occur mostly because of its proximity to and easier connection with the DO stated by the interlocutor: A: HazLO ya - B: Tenme paciencia, ya te dije que LO voy a hacer (this sounds slightly more natural and more frequent to me than: "Ya te dije que voy a hacerLO," where "lo" sounds too distant from the first "lo".

Comment: @Paco At the bottom of footnote 1 on the first page of this paper (https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://revistas-filologicas.unam.mx/anuario-letras/index.php/al/article/download/275/274&ved=0ahUKEwikoND64vfSAhVLFJAKHW_RAGkQFggYMAA&usg=AFQjCNF9gxbGf4vECzvI189vARdC_h1ENg&sig2=WgGFd4aSYKswEHdvFSAHkQ) I found something in line with my view: *Creo que, cuando el pronombre se antepone a la perífrasis, tal vez el hablante trata de poner mayor énfasis en el pronombre; mientras que cuando éste se pospone, quizá desea dar mayor relieve a la acción expresada por el sintagma.*

Comment: I wish the rules for using or not using "a" before a direct object were as simple as "animate" vs "inanimate"... In that case, I can not explain why, but it feels correct both ways to me, with "A esto" sounding more like I'm tired of it... perhaps I'm thinking in "damaging" it by throwing it away, as in item 1.2 h in here: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=ctMgM8Bp2D6ELPuNfg    But then again, if I move the object to the back: "voy a tirar esto", I wouldn't use "a esto" in no circumstance... I can't explain it... perhaps (yet another) dialectal thing from Buenos Aires...

Comment: @Gustavson In any case notice those *tal vez* and *quizá*. I'm still not convinced at all.

Comment: @Paco I said the difference was subtle and that that pronoun in front position could be only slightly stronger. Some speakers will agree, others won't.

Comment: @Wences "a" will only be used with inanimate nouns after the verb with prepositional verbs, in which case "a" will introduce the complement known as complemento de régimen, for example: *A eso hay que acceder cuanto antes . (Hay que acceder a eso)*. Notice that this does not apply to the case in question. where "eso" is the direct object: * *A esto lo voy a tirar / Lo voy a tirar a esto.* (wrong)

Comment: @Gustavson: Thanks! That does explain quite a few cases!